# How to send each data from a different MQTT topic to the Mysql database in a different column

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mqtt

I'm setting up a new server with python to get data from the cloud MQTT broker.I want to my code can send multiple data to MYSQL DB from different topic,and each data is placed in a different column.But, my code only can send data to one column now.How to fix it? Here is my code

```
enter code here
#!/usr/bin/env python 1
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import sys
import MySQLdb

# Koneksi ke database
try:
 db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","root","","mqtt")
except:
print("Failed to connect to Database")
print("Stop...")
sys.exit()

# Prepare cursor
cursor = db.cursor()

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the 
server.
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected: "+str(rc))

# Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
# reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("Current_Temperatur")
    client.subscribe("Current_Humidity")

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    lista = msg.topic
    sql = """INSERT INTO `mqtt`.`table` (`id`, `topic`, `sensor`, `date`) 
    VALUES (NULL, '""" + lista + """','""" + str(msg.payload) + """', 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);"""
try:
# save to mySQL
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
    print("Save to Database ... OK")
except:
    db.rollback()
    print("Save to Database ... Failed")

    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
try:
    client.connect("m16.cloudmqtt.com", 13959, 60)
except:
    print("Couldn't connect to MQTT Broker...")
    print("stop...")
    sys.exit()

    client.username_pw_set("asjsacsdjkc", "2121324352322")
try:
    client.loop_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:  #ctrl+C
    print("Stop...")
    db.close()
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you add a description of your table layout?

Comment: Why do you want to save different data into different columns? Right now it looks like each data is saved in a different row through a SQL insert command. This should be quite fine. Do you know about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)?

Comment: my expect table is id,topic,temp sensor, humidity sensor,date

Comment: Because I want to make each of these data into the graph

Comment: Can you post more information about your graph and how it should look like?

Comment: my graph shows about the condition of each topic (temperature or humidity) so I need 2 graphs where each graph contains "topic vs date (time)" meaning = graph 1 displays "temperature vs date" and graph 2 displays "humidity vs date" and it is displayed in web form

Comment: Then just use two SQL queries, one for temperature and the other one for humidity, and combine the results in your graph?